# If I post a question on Stack Overflow, then save it to Dropbox

Tags: if-this-then-that, stack-overflow

I want to create a new recipe on IFTTT:

- `if` I post a question on Stack Overflow, `then` save it to Dropbox.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure this is possible.

You can easily get an RSS feed of all your activity: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/4287698

(There's a link to "User Feed" in the lower right corner on your profile page.)

There's not, unfortunately, such a link for just your questions. Nor can you get an RSS feed for the advanced search `user:4287698 is:question`.

(If you look on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=rss+for+questions), there are a number of requests for more RSS feed options.)

So you could easily use the [Feed channel](http://ifttt.com/feed) to grab your feed and use the [Dropbox channel](http://ifttt.com/dropbox) to save each entry. To filter it to be just questions would require some other manipulation.

The Feed channel lets you filter by a simple phrase, but I'm having trouble finding something that would distinguish a question from other entry types. It looks like there's some tags for questions (`<category scheme="https://stackoverflow.com/tags" term="..." />`) but I'd expect that the XML wouldn't be searched. Maybe `https://stackoverflow.com/q/` would work, because I see that on questions and not answers. (I could be mis-reading the XML though.)

Comment: I also checked that, and noticed that `<id>https://stackoverflow.com/q/` will match for questions, and `<id>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/` will match for answers and comments. I just checked it on my StackOverflow user RSS, and it seems reliable (at least, I'm sure about the questions filter, and pretty sure about the answers+comments)